# Alpha/Beta participation questions

Tags: discussion

I wanted to know whether or not questions about the participation itself of a certain Alpha/Beta is on or off topic. Nowadays there are many games that let you participate in a Beta as a casual gamer, but you usually have to fulfill some conditions.

So would questions like:

- **"How can I raise my chance of getting invited to the new WoW beta?"**

or

- **"Where can I find a giveaway of Counter-Strike beta keys?"**

be on or off topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a huge range of different questions available to ask about alpha/beta. I'm not entirely clear if knowing this would be ["incidental knowledge"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8405/39891) or "Expert knowledge".

In any case these questions will still need to comply to the other parts of the FAQ/Help Center.

I don't know anything about your first question, but that might be because I don't know anything about the game. This question has to be evaluated to be incidental of expert knowledge since I'm also not sure that knowing a lot about WoW will help you with knowing this.

Your second example question would be off-topic. Because it is basically a shopping request.It also has a problem of having a very time-limited scope, since no answer will ever stay correct for long.  And neither of those are allowed. (I can't find the time-limited scope in the flag for closure reasons anymore though)

Comment: I assume you are talking about the "Too Localized" flag reason, which got dropped a while back.

Comment: Ah, yea, that'd be the one.